# Regular expression to parse combined log with strange user agent string

Tags: regex

I use the below regular expression to parse combined log format:-

```
^(?P<client>\S+) (?P<identd>\S+) (?P<userid>\S+) \[(?P<datetime>[^\]]+)\] "(?P<method>[A-Z]+) (?P<request>[^ "]+)? (?P<version>HTTP/[0-9.]+)" (?P<status>[0-9]{3}) (?P<size>[0-9]+|-) "(?P<referrer>[^"]*)" "{1,3}(?P<useragent>[^"]*)"{1,3} "(?P<cookie>[^"]*)"
```

It works find for most of the log but as times goes by, there are lots of useragent have strange " inside which makes the regular expression failed. I copied some of the problematic user agent below. Glad if someone could help to fix my regular expression so that it also works on the below strange scenario:-

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; tr-tr; PIRANHA BUSINESS TAB 7"" Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30 GSA/2.0.0.392829"
>
> "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0;
> Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; xhcueef7$#$%
> fjidf87jcnuFfFJH6@@jjfidjcu%09348%""=""IEAK)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like quotes are escaped with quotes. i.e.

If the `"` character is immediately followed by another `"` that should be treated as a single `"` for the value of the user agent.

Try changing this:

```
"{1,3}(?P<useragent>[^"]*)"{1,3}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

To this:

```
"(?P<useragent>(?:[^"]""|[^"])*)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]